# 'create email' shortcut vs. 'user initiated email'

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

We use 'journey builder' for sending email to a DE if we need a nurturing program, else we use 'create email' shortcut in email studio's overview section if we want to send email just once or to send email to a list (please correct me if this is not the right approach). However, there is one more option - 'user initiated email' in email studio's interactions section. Just wondering what is it for or if it gives some advantage over 'create email'. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[User Initiated Emails](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_user_initiated_email_interaction.htm&type=5) are used for bulk emails that will be repeatedly sent to the same list/data extension. For example, newsletters or monthly updates, etc. (This will send to the data in the chosen audience at send time, not limit it to the same exact people each time)

You basically set up all the same stuff you would in a wizard send email, but in advance for the send. (audience, delivery profile, subject, email, etc.)

This then forms a reusable object that you can use as a 'short cut' where you would just need to [set a schedule to send the email](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_user_initiated_email_interaction.htm&type=5), or you can add it into Automation Studio to automatically send the emails at a set interval.

Comment: Great info Gortonington. Just one clarification, if I created a user initiated email 'newsletter' and send it, next time when I need to send the newsletter, I need to updated email message only or can i update the email in the backend and it will automatically be updated in user initiated email? Thanks again.

Comment: I believe if the email is updated, you will need to update the UI Send. I originally thought that it would take the 'snapshot' after scheduling, but I believe I was proven wrong in this assumption and that the email 'snapshot' is taken at save/creation.